# Xamarin.Android targetting Android 4.4 (API 19) throws an error on startup using Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I can run my app without any problem on Android 6.0+ devices but I need strong retrocompatibility with Android 4.4.

I set up the target android version and the minimum version to KitKat leaving the compilation version to "use latest version". The app builds but doesn't run on my device or on the emulator [level 19] (I got the "app has stopped" alert than nothing). The app still works on newer devices.

I tried to set the compilation version to API Level 19 too but my app doesn't compile this way. I got this error:

`No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:elevation'`

So I tried to downgrade my Xamarin Forms packages from version 25.x.x to 19.x.x but nuget alerts me that those packages doesn't exists:

```
...
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations" version="19.0.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat" version="19.0.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
...
```

Comment: On logcat I found: `FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                Process: it.xxx.android, PID: 12703
                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application md58be93af4beb389e425842ea692c954d2.MainApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "md58be93af4beb389e425842ea692c954d2.MainApplication"`

Answer (score 0):

You should update Xamarin and Xamarin.Android to the latest stable channel. It must be fixed it by uninstalling the app, the shared mono runtime and `Xamarin.Android Api-23 Support` from my device and doing a clean rebuild.

In your device go to the ***settings -> apps -> all apps, and uninstall them.***

Answer (score 0):

> No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:elevation'

The `android:elevation` [attribute](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setElevation(float)) was introduced in 5.0, so it just work from the API level 21 and upper.